# Symbol or name referencing to the same glossary entry

Tags: glossaries

in my thesis, I often use either the name of an object or its symbol. For example, I use the term cost matrix and also the symbol `c_ij`. When reading either one I want to be able to click on it and get referenced to a glossary entry including the following:

cost matrix c_ij - Displays the costs for each customer

Currently, I use the following:

```
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{cost matrix}{name=cost matrix,
description={Displays the costs for each customer}}

\printglossary
```

Unfortunately, this does not include the symbol. Does any one know how to include the symbol as stated above?

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `symbol` key to add the symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc, acronym,style=tree]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{cost matrix}{name=cost matrix,
symbol={\ensuremath{c_{ij}}},
description={Displays the costs for each customer}}

\begin{document}
\gls{cost matrix} or \glssymbol{cost matrix}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: image of document]